# KeyOff without effect

Tags: objective-c, fmod

I'm using FMod for first time, and I don't understand why my code doesn't trigger Sound Designer's keyoff.

Working env

```
iOS
Xcode
```

Verified

```
.fev and event's keyoff tested with fmod_eventPlayer
all FOD_RESULT are OK
```

Here the code processed chronologically

```
-(void) initFmod
{
...
    //init
    result = _eventSystem->init(32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL | FMOD_INIT_ENABLE_PROFILE, NULL, FMOD_EVENT_INIT_NORMAL);
...

    //load music bank settings
    result        = FMOD_OK;
    [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/_music.fev", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]] getCString:buffer maxLength:200 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    result = _eventSystem->load(buffer, NULL, NULL);
...
}

-(void) onMusicGameStart
{

    ///////////// LOAD Game Music ////////////
    //Build Event name
    FMOD_RESULT result = FMOD_OK;
    NSString *musicGameEvent = @"music/music/music_sample_with_keyOff";
    const char *eventGame = [musicGameEvent UTF8String];

    //Get event from Fmod
    result = _eventSystem->getEvent(eventGame, FMOD_EVENT_DEFAULT, &_musicGame);

    result =  _musicGame->start();
...
}

-(void) stopMusic
{
    //Stop current Music
    [self triggerEventKeyoff:_musicGame];
}

-(void) triggerEventKeyoff:(FMOD::Event*)event
{
    if(event)
    {
        FMOD_RESULT result = FMOD_OK;
        //Get Event's Parameter
        FMOD::EventParameter *param;
        result = event->getParameterByIndex(0, &param);
        //Check error message
        [self checkResult:result even:nil];

        //trigger KeyOff
        if(result == FMOD_OK)
        {
            result = param->keyOff();
            //Check error message
            [self checkResult:result even:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

The music associated to _musicGame doesn't play its KeyOff and just continue playing.
_musicGame is only set in onMusicGameStart().

I don't know what to test from this point.

By the way, I'm not able to launch fmod_profiler (crash at launch).

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug with the current fmod_profiler, it's simple to fix though:

1. Open the terminal and navigate to the location of fmod_profiler.app
2. Navigate into fmod_profiler.app/Contents/MacOS
3. Type: "chmod u+x fmod_profiler

Now you can run the app properly from the finder.

Regarding keyoff, I would contact FMOD support.

Comment: :) yeah that was me at FMOD support.